# How to remove backtrace in activejob retry?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm running this background job and the retry block works, but I just don't want my log getting clogged with backtrace. Sidekiq has a `backtrace: false` options if I'm not mistaken, does activejob have something similar?

```
class SomeJob < ApplicationJob
  retry_on SomeCustomException do |exception|
    #this gets executed AFTER the backtrace has been executed
  end

  def perform
   raise SomeCustomException
  end
end
```

BACKTRACE:

```
[ActiveJob] [SomeJob] [76f9a4d2-ba00-463a-9d5b-2837a12b6e1e] 
Error performing SomeJob (Job ID: 76f9a4d2-ba00-463a-9d5b- 
2837a12b6e1e) from Async(default) in 4.52ms: 
SomeCustomException (SomeCustomException):

******MULTIPLE LINES OF CLUTTER HERE*******
```

Comment: Weren't you using any queuing adapter / back-end like sidekiq with ActiveJob?